# stunnel -starttls xmpp return "SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol"

Tags: mongoose, xmpp, ejabberd, stunnel

I want to proxy via stunnel to XMPP ejabberd/mongoose server.
Stunnel have a certs, client=no etc. Here is config:

```
cert = /home/user/ssl/CA/certs/server.cert.pem
key = /home/user/ssl/CA/private/server.nopass.key.pem

;sslVersion = TLSv1
sslVersion = all

setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4
pid= /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid

socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

verify = 2
CApath = /home/user/ssl/CA/certs
CAfile = /home/user/ssl/CA/certs/ca.cert.pem
CRLpath = /home/user/ssl/CA/crl/
CRLfile = /home/user/ssl/CA/crl/crl.pem
debug = info
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

[mongooseim]
accept = 5226
connect = 5222
```

And if I connect this way:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5226 -cert /home/user/ssl/CA/certs/username.cert.pem -key /home/user/ssl/CA/private/username.key.pem -verify 2
```

almost everything is fine. I mean that stunnel get no errors and xmpp server knows that something trying to connect to it.

But if I connect this way, as clients do (with -starttls xmpp):

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5226 -cert /home/user/ssl/CA/certs/username.cert.pem -key /home/user/ssl/CA/private/username.key.pem -verify 2 -starttls xmpp
```

I get an error in stunnel log:

```
SSL_accept: 140760FC: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

And xmpp server log is quiet, that means nothing is trying to connect to xmpp.

**What should I do for good working of client request with -startssl xmpp?**

Thank You.

Comment: Stunnel does not support starttls. You can see it in its code.